# Utility of the Derivative of Laplace Transforms for ODE's

Tags: laplace-transform

Many texts discuss the derivative of Laplace transform $dF(s)/ds$. In general, differentiation of a Laplace is equivalent to multiplying the original function by $t$, and vice versa. So, if $\mathscr{L}\{f(t)\} = F(s)$, then:
$$\mathscr{L}\{tf(t)\}=-\frac{dF(s)}{ds} $$
Similarly, if $\mathscr{L}\{f'(t)\} = sF(s) - f(0)$, then:
$$\begin{split}\mathscr{L}\{{tf'(t)}\}&=-\frac{d}{ds}\left\{sF(s) - f(0)\right\}\\
                                       &=-s\frac{dF(s)}{ds} - F(s)\end{split}$$
The problem (my problem) with the last equation is that a derivative with non-constant coefficient $(tf'(t))$ yielded a derivative with non-constant coefficient $(sF'(s))$. How then would this transform be useful? Are there any examples of the utility of this property of Laplace transforms.

Comment: generally it's not convenient. see p.70 http://www.javaquant.net/papers/Laplacetransform.pdf for some examples. you may get integral representation of special functions more directly as far as i know

Answer (score -2):

This can be used to solve differential equations having a derivative term multiplied by $t$. *e.g.* : $$t\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dt}=t.$$